# Mongoose, how to append element to an array, inside existing JSON document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

#### The Situation

I have a MongoDB of the following data structure

```
teamName: (String)
data: (Array)
---date: (Timestamp)
---userResults: (Object)
------userHash: (StringHash)
------score: (String)
------comment: (String)
```

[Here is a short example on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/m9qpAWej).

---

#### The Question

Given a specific `teamName` and `date` (within the team data array), I'd like to append a new row (`{userHash: '', score: '', comment: ''}`) into `userResults` array.

**How can I update an array within a given document, after querying the parent node, and the parents parent node?**

---

#### What I've tried so far

I've tried `findOneAndUpdate`. It inserted an entire new document, right from the root though.

```
TeamRecordSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
    {teamName: teamName, data: {date: today}}, 
    {$set:{teamName: teamName, data: {date: today, userResults: [userResponse]}}}, 
    {new: true, upsert: true}, 
    function(err, savedDoc){

       // Do stuff with err and savedDoc

});
```

I've tried `save`, and again it just creates an entire new document at the root level, within my db

```
const _userResponse = new TeamRecordSchema(teamUserResponse);
_userResponse.save((err, savedDoc) => {

    // Do stuff with err and savedDoc accordingly     

 });
```

I've also tried several variations based on the documentation, but I either get the same results, or an error.

Comment: This should work `TeamRecordSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
    {teamName: teamName, 'data.date': today}}, 
    {$push:{'data.$.userResults': {userHash: '', score: '', comment: ''}}}, 
    {new: true, upsert: true}, 
    function(err, savedDoc){
});`

Comment: @Veeram, legend!! Thanks so much, that works perfectly, and is exactly what I'd been trying to do for the last 12 hours! 
If you put it as an answer, I'll accept (if you'd like the rep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`$positional`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator.

You include the field (`date`) from the `data` to locate the index of element and replace the placeholder(`$`) with the found index from query part in the update part to push the element in `userResults`.

```
TeamRecordSchema.findOneAndUpdate( 
  {teamName: teamName, 'data.date': today}}, 
  {$push:{'data.$.userResults': {userHash: '', score: '', comment: ''}}}, 
  {new: true, upsert: true}, 
   function(err, savedDoc){ }
);
```